# Structural subtyping reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, structural-typing

Can we get the type of `val s: String` using reflection from the outside of the function `f`?

```
val f = (r: {val s: String}) => {
}
```

Comment: Under 2.9 or 2.10 or does it not matter?

Comment: It does not matter 2.9 or 2.10. But I'm usually using 2.9.2.

Comment: I highly doubt it's possible in 2.9 without working with compiler. In 2.10 there is the reflection api that probably will allows inspection of the type of `r`.

Comment: Using [this info](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs-2.10.x/library/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Mirrors) I've tried to reflect on the anonymous function with 2.10.0-RC1 as follows, but stuck on it erasing the type of anonymous function parameters - it could be a bug, I'll report it: `import reflect.runtime._, universe._; currentMirror.reflectClass(currentMirror.reflect(f).symbol).symbol.typeSignature.member(newTermName("apply")).asTerm.alternatives.map(_.typeSignature)`

Comment: That's not a bug. `currentMirror.reflect(f)` reflects upon a runtime value, therefore it only has access to runtime type information, erased during compilation.

Comment: If you force generation of compile-time type info with type tags, then everything's going to be fine. See my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>ru}

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> def typeOf[T: ru.TypeTag](x: T) = ru.typeOf[T] // capture compile-time type info
typeOf: [T](x: T)(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])reflect.runtime.universe.Type

scala> val f = (r: {val s: String}) => {}
f: AnyRef{val s: String} => Unit = <function1>

scala> val tpe = typeOf(f)
tpe: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.AnyRef{val s: String} => Unit

scala> ru.showRaw(tpe)
res0: String = TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Function1, List(RefinedType(List(TypeRef(ThisType(scala), newTypeName("AnyRef"), List())), Scope(newTermName("s"))), TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Unit, List())))

scala> val ru.TypeRef(_, _, refinement :: _) = tpe
refinement: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.AnyRef{val s: String}
```

With Scala reflection one can also generate mocks for structural types as follows: https://gist.github.com/4008389. The linked gist does this using toolboxes and runtime reflection, but this scenario looks implementable with macros as well.

Comment: Which version of Scala do you use? I get a warning on the last statement: `warning: abstract type pattern reflect.runtime.universe.TypeRef is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`

Comment: The import is necessary. It brings a class tag for TypeRef into scope, which eliminates the unchecked warning.

Comment: Is there any way to create instance of refinement?

Comment: @sndyuk I don't think so. Refinement types are only used during typecheck, no classes are generated for them. So to begin with we have nothing to instantiate.

Comment: @sschaef This happens because `TypeRef` is an abstract type (scala.reflect.api.Types#TypeRef) and abstract types are erased during compilation, losing their identity. Therefore when the pattern matcher tries to emit `something.isInstanceOf[TypeRef]`, this causes an unchecked warning. However when there's an implicit classtag in scope, the pattern matcher can make use of it to emit something like `classtag.runtimeClass.isAssignableFrom(something.getClass)` (where classtag points to the underlying scala.reflect.internal.Types#TypeRef, which is a full-fledged class, not an abstract type).

Comment: @sndyuk If you're really determined, you can use runtime compilation (which we introduced along with Scala reflection) to generate the necessary classes. If that's what you want, please, ask me for details.